# How do you see which user uploaded an Imgur album?

Tags: images, profile, imgur

I do know that it was uploaded by a registered user, because I've been to their profile before from their album, but I can't find the link anymore.

Comment: I guess that the UI was changed, because right now the username is exactly under the post title. Am I right? Or it still can't be found easily for you?